# HTML5 FIle API: Security Error while reading a file

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fileapi

*Problem solved, read comment*

The third problem I have with the HTML5 File API:
I still use Chrome 12 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard and I'm still trying to read files with the HTML5 File API, but FileHandler.error() get called because a "SECURITY_ERR" occurres.
The file I try to read is a regular .txt file from my desktop, but it neither works with other files although I can open them with regular applications.

```
function FileHandler(files, action) {
    console.log('FileHandler called.');

    this.files = files;
    this.reader = new FileReader();
    this.action = action;

    this.handle = function() {
        console.log('FileHandler.handle called.');

        for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            this.reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }
    }

    this.upload = function() {
        console.log('FileHandler.upload called.');
        console.log(this.reader);

        data = {
            content: this.reader.result
        }

        console.log(data);
    }

    this.error = function() {
        console.log('An error occurred while reading the file.');
        console.log(this.reader.error);
    }

    this.reader.onload = this.upload.bind(this);
    this.reader.onerror = this.error.bind(this);
}
```

The code generates the following console output:
http://cl.ly/1x1o2F0l2m3L1T2c0H0i

Comment: Problem solved! I just uploaded the script to a webspace it works perfect.

Comment: If you're testing an app from `file://`, you can run Chrome with the following flags: `--allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access`. This should only be used for testing purposes.

Comment: @ebidel You should add that comment as an answer so this post can be closed :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're testing an app from `file://`, you can run Chrome with the following flags: `--allow-file-access-from-files` `--allow-file-access`. This should only be used for testing purposes.

Comment: So there's no way to use a file reader on a website basically ? You can't require your users to start their chrome browser with a special flag :S

Comment: No `file://` protocol will only be used when testing the website locally without any server running, once deployed the file will be transfered over `http://` protocol

Comment: If a tablet executes a HTML5 application, will it be using a file:// or http:// protocol? And if it is the latter, will it runs into this error too?

Comment: +1 for the file/http hint. But I created a Chrome shortcut and added mentioned flags as parameters and it doesn't work. How should I use those flags?