# File input and Dart

Tags: file-upload, dart

I'm trying out Dart, but I cant figure out, how to send an image from the user to the server. I have my input-tag, and i can reach this in the DART code, but i cant seem to read from it. Im trying something like:

```dart
InputElement ie = document.query('#myinputelement');

ie.on.change.add((event){<br/>
    InputElement iee = document.query('#myinputelement');<br/>
    FileList mfl =  iee.files;<br/>
    File myFile = mlf.item(0);<br/>

    FileReader fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsBinaryString(myFile);

    String result = fr.result; //this is always empty
});
```

With the html containing:

```html
<input type="file" id="myinputelement">
```

I really hope you cant help me, im kinda stuck. I might just be missing how to do the onload for the filereader,  or maybe im doing it totally wrong.

Comment: Are you loading your page in Chrome via `file://` protocol? If so, you might need to enable some flags http://stackoverflow.com/a/7691772/180740 -- or upload the files somehwere to access them via HTTP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [FileReader](http://api.dartlang.org/html/FileReader.html) API is asynchronous so you need to use event handlers.

```dart
var input = window.document.querySelector('#upload');
Element log = query("#log");

input.addEventListener("change", (e) {
  FileList files = input.files;
  Expect.isTrue(files.length > 0);
  File file = files.item(0);

  FileReader reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onLoad = (fileEvent) {
    print("file read");
    log.innerHTML = "file content is ${reader.result}";
  };
  reader.onerror = (evt) => print("error ${reader.error.code}");
  reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

you also need to allow file uploads from to your browser, which can be done in Chrome by starting it with the flag **--allow-file-access-from-files**

Comment: I am trying to only use the dart:html atm(you cant use both :/). While using the dart:html, you cant add the handlers to the filereader. Hope you cant help :p

Comment: added example of using both libraries together

Answer (score 6):

This is how to read a file using `dart:html`.

```
document.querySelector('#myinputelement`).onChange.listen((changeEvent) {
    List fileInput = document.querySelector('#myinputelement').files;

    if (fileInput.length > 1) {
        // More than one file got selected somehow, could be a browser bug.
        // Unless the "multiple" attribute is set on the input element, of course
    }
    else if (fileInput.isEmpty) {
        // This could happen if the browser allows emptying an upload field
    }

    FileReader reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onLoad.listen((fileEvent) {
          String fileContent = reader.result;
          // Code doing stuff with fileContent goes here!
    });

    reader.onError.listen((itWentWrongEvent) {
          // Handle the error
    });

    reader.readAsText(fileInput[0]);
});
```

Comment: `The getter 'files' isn't defined for the type 'Element'.
Try importing the library that defines 'files', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'files'.dartundefined_getter`

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary (any more) to use dart:dom FileReader instead of the one from dart:html.

Your code should work if you add an event listener to the file reader, like this:

```dart
FileReader fr = new FileReader();
fr.on.load.add((fe) => doSomethingToString(fe.target.result));
fr.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

My attempt

```
  void fileSelected(Event event) async {
    final files = (event.target as FileUploadInputElement).files;
    if (files.isNotEmpty) {
      final reader = new FileReader();

      // ignore: unawaited_futures
      reader.onError.first.then((evt) => print('error ${reader.error.code}'));
      final resultReceived = reader.onLoad.first;
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files.first);

      await resultReceived;
      imageReference.fileSelected(reader.result as List<int>);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from this post, I got it to work. I still utilized my event handler in the input tag and made sure that I **DID NOT** import both dart:io and dart:html, **only dart:html is needed**.

This is what my final AppComponent looked like.

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: [coreDirectives],
)

class AppComponent {
  // Stores contents of file upon load
  String contents;

  AppComponent();

  void fileUpload(event) {
    // Get tag and the file 
    InputElement input = window.document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    File file = input.files[0];

    // File reader and event handler for end of loading
    FileReader reader = FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onLoad.listen((fileEvent) {
      contents = reader.result;
    });
  }
}
```

This is what my template looks like:

```
<h1>File upload test</h1>
<input type="file" (change)="fileUpload($event)" id="fileUpload">
<div *ngIf="contents != null">
    <p>Hi! These are the contents of your file:</p>
    <p>{{contents}}</p>
</div>
```