# How to pick file for upload server in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dio

I want to pick a file from computer for upload server, but I don't know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58121886/3043944) about accessing the file and reading its contents. It could be a good start for you.

In short

1. Create a `FileUploadInputElement` from the `dart:html` package like this. `FileUploadInputElement element = FileUploadInputElement()..id = "file_input";`.
2. Use `dart:ui` 's `platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory` method to register your element.

```
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory("add_input", (int viewId) {
      return element;
    });
```

3. Use `HTMLElementView` widget to attach this element to your web app layout.

`HtmlElementView(viewType: 'add_input')`

4. Use a `FileReader` to read the files available through `FileUploadInputElement.files` as follows.

`fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(element.files[0]);`

5. Handle `onLoad` and `onError` events if necessary.
6. On click of your upload button, process the `FileUploadInputElement.files` array to access the files and upload it to the server.

Comment: How to associate uploaded files with http requests？

Comment: you can use `http.post` from the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package.

Comment: Because the FileUploadInputElement.files object and http's post file are not the same object, I can't put FileUploadInputElement.files to http's post file params. How can I do?

Comment: You can post the byte array and decode it in the server. 
check [FileReader](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-html/FileReader-class.html) for more options like reading as text. But format of the data being sent is your choice and is something you will have to research how to do it.

Comment: Well, I know how to do, Thanks!