# How can i implement Flutter File Picker in Website

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How can we choose file from local system drives in Flutter web development . Not in App
Please any one suggest me .

I am using like this
I can able to choose file
But how can i get the file path

[image]

Comment: Please provide more info to help and remember to post code snippet with error log as text not as screenshot.

Comment: Please check these two posts. [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120098/how-to-get-the-file-selected/58121886#58121886), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252856/how-to-pick-files-and-images-for-upload-with-flutter-web). Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the file selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120098/how-to-get-the-file-selected)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data and create a MediaInfo class for it

```
class MediaInfo{
  String fileName;
  String filePath;
}
```

Get File Path

```
Future<MediaInfo> convertFileGetNamePath({@required html.File file}) async {
  final Map<String, dynamic> infoData = {};
  final reader = html.FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
  await reader.onLoad.first;
  final fileName = file.name;
  infoData.addAll({
    'name': fileName,
    'path': filePath,
  });

  MediaInfo webImageInfo = MediaInfo();
  webImageInfo.fileName = infoData['name'];
  webImageInfo.filePath = infoData['path'];
  return webImageInfo;

}
```

Implement it in your code

```
MediaInfo getInfo = await convertFileGetNamePath(file: imageFile);
fileName = getInfo.fileName;
```